# Django templates and views

Tags: python, django, templates, ckeditor, models

I am in a bit of a jam here. I am doing a simple conversion of a website from html to a Django-driven site, it has no special content, 3 pages (cv/about/projects) and is a bit of a web portfolio.

I want to use CKEditor to enable editing of the pages via the admin interface.
I also want to be able to use the Django templates.

When create the Pages from the CK-edit-interface and add content into the 'content'-field I am not able to access the pages as templates.

The code I think is important for my question:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import HTMLField

class Page(models.Model):
  title =  models.CharField(max_length=30)
  content = HTMLField(blank=True, verbose_name='HTML version')
  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.title
```

views.py:

```
def cv(request):
  cv = Page.objects.filter(id=2)
  content = ([p.content for p in cv])
      return HttpResponse(content)
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^cv$', cv),
```

I read about Context & loader to make pages dynamic using templates, so I wrote this view:

views.py:

```
from django.template import Context, loader

def about(request):
  about = Page.objects.filter(id=1)
  t = loader.get_template('about.html')
  ct = Context({
  'about': about
  })
  return HttpResponse(t.render(ct))
```

But then I need to update the pages via their respective .html file and the CKEdit-interface does not *reach* my pages. Anyone know what I got to refactor, add to be able to use the Django Templates to edit my pages? (Using the {% block content %}{% endblock %} ) *While still being able to use the CKEditor to edit the content of these pages.*

Comment: I don't understand what exactly do you mean? You have some data for your pages, you get that data in the views and send it to template. Then template displays this data somehow according to template rules. What else do you need? Also, please show up your templates.

Comment: Well, the templates are empty, they are there, there's a cv.html a about.html and a projects.html but the templates are empty. I am guessing my urls and my views are written in the wrong way, when I go got localhost/cv I get the page generated via the admin interface, not the template. I am unable to link the template to the page that I am creating in the admin interface, which is what I want. But I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending some base template, say "base.html", then I would imagine:

base.html

```
<html>
    <body>
    {% block header %}
        My header
    {% endblock header %}
    {% block content %}
        My content
    {% endblock content %}
    </body>
</html>
```

about.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {{ about.content }}
{% endblock content %}
```

You passed the `about` context variable to about.html, so you need to call that variable.  Basically, your templates cannot be completely empty.  Even if about.html contained nothing more than `{{ about.content }}`.  I don't think you have given enough information to determine the part about CKE, but first start by making sure you can render something, anything, to the template, then tackle CKE